# Ruby/Amazon Route 53 Ruby gem syntax and usage

Tags: ruby, rubygems, routes

I wondered if anyone can help me, I am fairly new at ruby, and have got a bit stuck when trying to write a script utilising the Amazon Web Service Route53 gem.

When using the example script to create a new zone, and create records with it it works fine. however, im not sure how to specify the zone when creating a CNAME record. the new_zone object is different, and im not sure how it works.

I am trying to do this, simply create a new cname record. I am using the documentation here:
http://rubydoc.info/gems/route53/0.2.1/frames

```
new_zone = 'abcd.net. /hostedzone/Z4W3K5G8FBG6R'

new_record = Route53::DNSRecord.new("cbs.abcd.net.","CNAME","3600",["abcd.net."],new_zone)
resp = new_record.create
```

how do I specify the zone?
I try to do it with a string, but it fails...

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/route53-0.2.1/lib/route53.rb:364:in `create': undefined method `perform_actions' for "abcd.net. /hostedzone/Z4W3K5G8FBG6R":String (NoMethodError)
    from ./cname.rb:12
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be resolved, just I found this question:

```
require 'route53'

HOSTED_ZONE_ID = "your_hosted_zone_id"

conn = Route53::Connection.new('AccessKey', 'SecretKey')
new_zone = Route53::Zone.new("example.com.", "/hostedzone/#{HOSTED_ZONE_ID}", conn) # you need to pass connection
new_record = Route53::DNSRecord.new("foo.example.com.","CNAME","3600", ["example.com."],new_zone)
resp = new_record.create
```

Answer (score 0):

The new_zone variable is not a string, but is a Route53::Zone object.

If you want to use an existing zone, you'll either need to fetch the existing zone objects into an array like this:

```
conn = Route53::Connection.new('access_key','secret_key')
zones = conn.get_zones("abcd.net.")
new_record = Route53::DNSRecord.new("cbs.abcd.net.", "CNAME", "3600", ["abcd.net."], zones.first)
resp = new_record.create
```

or, initialize a Route53::Zone object like this:

```
conn = Route53::Connection.new('access_key','secret_key')
zone = Route53::Zone.new("abcd.net.", "/hostedzone/Z4W3K5G8FBG6R", conn)
new_record = Route53::DNSRecord.new("cbs.abcd.net.", "CNAME", "3600", ["abcd.net."], zone)
resp = new_record.create
```

(I guess this repeats the answer above, but a bit more explanation helps)